Is there a recently published Flora of Japan in English?
I am currently getting into the study of the flora of east asia. For China, Taiwan and Korea I could quickly find modern treatises, see 1-3 below. But not for Japan, to my surprise: Even after quite some searching all I could find is a 111 year old text, see 4.

Question: Is there a more recent English language publication on the Flora of Japan?


Hong, D.Y. & Blackmore S. (Ed.) (2015). Plants of China. A
companion to the Flora of China.  Cambridge University Press, New
York

Chang-Fu, H. & Chung-Fu S. (2019). Introduction to  the
flora of Taiwan, 1: geography, geology, climate,  and soils.
Department of Botany, National Taiwan  University, Taipei

Lee, Y.-N. (2006). New Flora of Korea.  Kyo-Hak publishing,
Seoul

Takeda, H. (1913). The Vegetation of Japan.
The New Phytologist, 12(2): 37-58


